# Is there a way to stop ColdFusion 11 from caching Fusebox circuit.xml.cfm files?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, fusebox

Is there a way to stop ColdFusion 11 from caching Fusebox circuit.xml.cfm files?

I have to restart the coldfusion service every time I make a change to a fuseaction file and it's getting tiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 settings in play here. One is "trusted cache" - a setting in the CF admin that does not "check" for a modification once a class has been compiled. You can turn trusted cache off and CF will begin to check for modifications.

The second (and more likely) setting is "parsed" setting. This setting actually saves all your include files into a "parsed" directory and compiles the from there. You can try adding the following to your URL:

Fusebox.parseall=true  or alternately Fusebox.loadclean=true  - one of these might work.

Finally there is a "mode" setting you can modify to "development" from "production" - that will cause the whole thing to be reparsed.

This is from memory - but maybe it will be enough to get you going. good luck! :)